# PCRE Regex matching spaces in formatted currency

Tags: php, regex, pcre, removing-whitespace, currency-formatting

For a project I need to substitute spaces with an `&nbsp;` if - and only if - they occur inside a predefined currency format.

For example:

```
EUR 1.2
EUR 1.23
EUR 12
EUR 123
EUR 12 Mio.
EUR 12 345 Mio.
GBP 1 123 456 789 Mio. <---- this one is a problem, only matching the first, second to last and last one, but not those inbetween
USD 12 million
EUR 1.23 billion
```

So basically [CurrencyPrefix][space][amount[with_spaces]][Suffix]

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
(?:EUR|USD|GBP)(\ )(?:(?:(?:\d+(\ ))+\d+)|\d+\.\d+|\d+)+(?:(\ )(?:Mio\.|million|billion))?
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/z73ISR/5

Problem is: it only matches the space 3 times. I need to match it [n] times (see the GBP example).

Comment: Just create a bash script that takes advantage of a `while` loop and `sed`...

Comment: I've edited your question and brought that html entity into consideration. If that's not right please be more clear about the substitution part.

Comment: Try `(?:EUR|USD|GBP|\G(?!^)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\K( +)`. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/ENaJfS/1

Comment: @revo: Post that regex as answer.

Comment: What does your entire actual line of data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match all spaces starting from currency abbrev to all those between and after digits you will need to work with `\G` metacharacter:

```
(?:EUR|USD|GBP|\G(?!^)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\K +
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/ENaJfS/1)

This is the explanation:

- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `EUR|USD|GBP` Match one of the currency names
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Start match from where it ends previously
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a sequence of digits following an optional fractional part
- `)` End of non-capturing
- `\K +` Reset match output and immediately look for spaces

Comment: Thank you. That (almost) works. Unfortunately it also captures a trailing whitespace that should'nt be captured. Updated your regex with some examples. Will work it out from there.

https://regex101.com/r/ENaJfS/2

Comment: @bberger You're welcome. What there specifically should I spot? What's the problem?

Comment: @revo 
The cost of fish was EUR 1.2 yesterday. <--- caputres the space between 1.2 and "yesterday".
EUR 1.23 is the amount charged <--- same here ("1.23" and "is").

It should only capture those when the segment ends with "Mio.|million|billion"

Comment: @bberger Well, then you need to explicitly say what should come after. Put `(?=\d+|Mio|million|billion)` at the end of regex for it to work. See live demo here https://regex101.com/r/ENaJfS/3

Comment: @revo you're awesome! Thank you very much! Didn't even know \G and \K existed - learning never stops :)